# How to show Drawer content below Drawer Header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using Drawer Navigator from the package of reactnavigation to build a Drawer in our react native project, i want to place drawer below of header like image B,how to do that,
using `header: (props) => {return <DrawerHeader {...props} />},` and content as
`drawerContent={(props) => {return <DrawerContent {...props} />}}`thanks.

```
      <Drawer.Navigator 
      
                header: (props) => {return <DrawerHeader {...props} />},
              
              }}
              drawerContent={(props) => {

                return <DrawerContent {...props} />

              }}         
        >
          .....
        </Drawer.Navigator >
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing header component separately you can directly paas it in the drawerContent

```
<Drawer.Navigator 
  drawerContent={(props) => {
  return( 
  <>
  <DrawerHeader {...props} />
  <DrawerContent {...props} />
  </>)
   }}         
    >
      .....
</Drawer.Navigator >
```

this way you could style the drawer more efficiently.

Comment: yeah, its an another idea, but we need header in every screens  too